# No JTA UserTransaction available

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jboss

**Background** I'm using spring, jboss, java. Below is my configuration for spring  JtaTransactionManager.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="150" />
    </bean>
```

**ISSUE:**

I'm facing below issue not while running application server (JBOSS), because I believe Jboss is binding to default transaction manager. However while I'm running integration test cases loading of springapplicationcontext fails with below error.

```
BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transac
tionManager' defined in class path resource [spring-container.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'tra
nsactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
```

Is there a way we can ask spring to use default transaction, if application server is not provided?
By not making any changes in this file, since my usage is only for test cases not recommended to change in actual code.

Comment: I tried updating with below changes:

`<bean id="localUserTransaction" class="org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalUserTransaction"/>
 
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
  <property name="userTransaction" ref = "localUserTransaction"/>
 </bean>`

***I faced below issue::*


JTA implementation does not support nested transactions; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: COM00100: Method "createNewTransaction" of class "org.wildfly.transaction.c
lient.spi.LocalTransactionProvider$1" is not implemented

Comment: check this schema for all properties: https://springframework.org/tx/spring-tx.xsd